# Apache2 rotatelogs not truncating file

Tags: apache, apache2

I have rotatelogs setup how I believe it should be given my requirements.  Below are the relevant lines:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs -l -n 4 /var/www/html/org/logs/development/ssl.access_log 604800" combined
ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs -l -n 4 /var/www/html/org/logs/development/ssl.error_log 604800"
```

My understanding is that weekly, I should see a new log file get created with a different suffix.  `-n 4` would keep three weeks of logs plus the current file being written to.  I only only seeing a `ssl.access_log.1` and then the current log file.  However, the log file without a suffix is massive and inspecting it's content I can see that there are messages from LONG ago.

Am I simply not grasping how rotatelogs functions?

UPDATE:

I'm beginning to wonder if the `rotationtime` argument to rotatelogs is specific to the time that the process has been running and not the time that the log file has been around.  logrotate is ran daily via a cron job that ultimately picks up a default logrotate config file for apach2 which rotates the default log files and also reloads apache2 every morning at 0625.  I am wondering if this reload is what causes my `rotationtime` argument of 604800 (7 days) to essentially never be reached thus causing the log file to never rotate.  On the right track?

Answer (score 0):

I'm observing exactly the same behaviour of rotatelogs: The file without suffix is never truncated, but still gets lines appended. In contrast to tczx3, I do not explicitely restart the processes regularly. Nor do I manupulate any timestamps. The behaviour is in my understanding clearly not like documented. And rotatelogs cannot count to 5 it seems. It is started with -n 5 but maintains only 4 files (without suffix, .1, .2 and .3).
I manually removed the outdated lines now from the files without suffix and shall watch over the next weeks. According to what I'll see, I'll open a bug report.